# Split string based on capitalized word using r

Tags: r, string, stringr, strsplit, capitalization

I have a string that I would like to split into several strings.

```
library(stringr)
testString <- "SMITH, Klaus, text, text, SMITH, Samantha, text, text,  MUELLER, Klaus, text, text,  MUELLER, Klara, text, text"
```

Whenever a new word is completely capitalised (followed by a comma) it should start a new string. At the end it should look like this:

```
[1] "VOLZ, Klaus, text, text,"
[2] "MUELLER, Klaus, text, text,"
[3] "MUELLER, Klara, text, text,"
```

I have tried different code here with strsplit, but I can't get r to say that it should not only search for a letter but a complete word (which can have a different number of letters) and then split the string.

```
strsplit(testString, "(?!^)(?<=[[:upper:]]{2})", perl=T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex lookaround - match one or more space (`\\s+`) that precedes one or more uppercase letter followed by a `,` (`(?=[A-Z]+,)`)

```
strsplit(testString, "\\s+(?=[A-Z]+,)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

-output

```
[1] "SMITH, Klaus, text, text," 
[2] "SMITH, Samantha, text, text," 
[3] "MUELLER, Klaus, text, text," 
[4] "MUELLER, Klara, text, text"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. This solves my problem

Comment: If this response works for you @JohnnyKing take a moment to mark it as the answer to your question. More about what that means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).